# I want to log data in a file which is displayed on java console when I run .jar file

Tags: java, jar, ifstream

I have a `.jar` file I am executing that with `java -jar file_name.jar`.

Then the program outputs to the IDE console, a prompt asking the user for credentials. After authenticating, the program prints database data to the console.

How can I redirect the console data output to a filestream?

I tried adding `logger` while executing the command `java -jar file_name.jar`. But no success.

I am not a java person, so I don't have any idea how to do that.
Any suggestion or help will be great.

**EDIT**

Screenshot addded for the GUI screen
[image]

Comment: _"then it shows the GUI console"_ either the GUI or the Console, they are completely opposite of each other. Do you have access to the source code? Or you want to do the logging directly with the cmd?

Comment: @NabeelOmer -  Sorry my bad, yes it is GUI window

Comment: @NabeelOmer -  I have access to the code, I tried editing its java files. But it gives me so many errors. It will be great if I can achieve this from command line

Comment: guys I am not a java developer, If something is wrong I puted let me know. Giving downvoting doesn't solve my problem. And if you think question is not good, let me know in comment

Comment: There was an answer which used `java.util.Logging` but unfortunately is now been deleted.

Comment: There is an answer below which shows how to do it from the command line `java -jar class.jar <someFile.file> 1>> log.txt` this ought to solve your problem.

Comment: @NabeelOmer -  It doesn't work for me, any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

if it's from java console:

```
java -jar class.jar <someFile.file> 1>> log.txt
```

Comment: @aurelies - thanks you so much for the reply. I will try this and will update you

Comment: so the console is a GUI console?

Comment: Yes should I update my question with screenshot, if it helps you to understand. If my question is not clear enough

Comment: you should specify in your question

Comment: do you have access to the sources from the jar you execute?

Comment: Yes, I have the access

Comment: please add this in your question

Answer (score 0):

since you said that you have access to the jar's sources then the simplest way you can just add the following at startup class:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

Handler handler = new FileHandler("test.log", LOG_SIZE, LOG_ROTATION_COUNT);
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLogger").addHandler(handler);
```

and with logger you log what you log in the console.

You can specify your own values for LOG_SIZE and LOG_ROTATION_COUNT

You may, if you want, adjust the logging level to suit.

Comment: I tried putting logger in the source file but, that is a `.java` file which I have to then compile which will give me a `.class` file and then I have to create a `.jar` file. But when I compile java file, it gives me lot of errors